# Should I recommend sealing classes by default?

Tags: c#, java, .net, oop

In a big project I work for, I am considering recommending other programmers to always seal their classes if they haven't considered how their classes should be subclassed. Often times, less-experienced programmers never consider this.

I find it odd that in Java and C# classes are non-sealed / non-final by default. I think making classes sealed greatly improves readability of the code.

Notice that this is in-house code that we can always change should the rare case occur that we need to subclass.

What are your experiences? I meet quite some resistance to this idea. Are people that lazy they could not be bothered to type `sealed`?

Comment: Subclassing is **rare**?!

Comment: How does sealing a class improve it's readability?

Comment: Maybe exaggerating a little, but I must have used the `sealed` keyword on a class I have written like a couple of times in my career. So, no, don't recommend something like this or [Anders Hejlsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) will be mad at you.

Comment: 99% of our classes are not subclassed

Comment: Readability is improved as you know you wont have to look else where in order to see all usages.

Comment: This is a controversial topic. Personally I wish C# classes were sealed by default too, but there are plenty of smart people on both sides...

Comment: @Darin: Does that mean that for all the other classes you've written, you've considered the implications of subclassing, and have documented expectations of subclasses? I like Josh Bloch's approach of "design for inheritance or prohibit it."

Comment: In C# methods are non-overrideable by default, and Code-Contracts enables correct subtyping. Thus sealing a class only makes code less reusable, and make the paradigm more module-oriented than object-oriented.

Comment: @Jon, to be honest, no, I don't usually do all you describe when I write a class in C# :-)

Comment: If 99% of your classes do not involve inheritance then it would seem the "don't subclass" convention is already entrenched in your org, and you don't need to enforce it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Okay, as so many other people have weighed in...

Yes, I think it's entirely reasonable to recommend that classes are sealed by default.

This goes along with the recommendation from Josh Bloch in his *excellent* book [Effective Java, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683):

> Design for inheritance, or prohibit it.

Designing for inheritance is *hard*, and can make your implementation *less* flexible, especially if you have virtual methods, one of which calls the other. Maybe they're overloads, maybe they're not. The fact that one calls the other *must be documented* otherwise you can't override either method safely - you don't know when it'll be called, or whether you're safe to call the other method without risking a stack overflow.

Now if you later want to change which method calls which in a later version, you can't - you'll potentially break subclasses. So in the name of "flexibility" you've actually made the implementation *less* flexible, and had to document your implementation details more closely. That doesn't sound like a great idea to me.

Next up is immutability - I like immutable types. I find them easier to reason about than mutable types. It's one reason why the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) API is nicer than using `Date` and `Calendar` in Java. But an unsealed class can never be *known* to be immutable. If I accept a parameter of type `Foo`, I may be able to rely on the properties *declared in `Foo`* not to be changed over time, but I can't rely on the object itself not being modified - there could be a mutable property in the subclass. Heaven help me if that property is also used by an override of some virtual method. Wave goodbye to many of the benefits of immutability. (Ironically, Joda Time has very large inheritance hierarchies - often with things saying "subclasses should be immutable. The large inheritance hierarchy of `Chronology` made it hard to understand when porting to C#.)

Finally, there's the aspect of overuse of inheritance. Personally I favour composition over inheritance where feasible. I love polymorphism for interfaces, and *occasionally* I use inheritance of implementation - but it's rarely a great fit in my experience. Making classes sealed avoids them being *inappropriately* derived from where composition would be a better fit.

EDIT: I'd also like to point readers at [Eric Lippert's blog post from 2004](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-are-so-many-of-the-framework-classes-sealed) on why so many of the framework classes are sealed. There are plenty of places where I wish .NET provided an *interface* we could work to for testability, but that's a slightly different request...

Comment: Here's the thing: I agree with the quote.  My problem is this: if you're writing code with sealed as a default, you're acknowledging the possibility in the future of it becoming unsealed, which would mean you're working from a more restricted to less restricted model, which can cause problems.  I would contend that if you truly want to write code that is sealed by default, you should not be writing that code in a language which has inheritance.  Perhaps using a tool which more appropriately has a default behavior of composition over inheritance is more appropriate.

Comment: @Paul: It would certainly be nice if C# and Java encouraged composition more... but you can still work with them in a compositional way reasonably easily. And while yes, there can certainly be drawbacks in moving from sealed to unsealed, at least it's feasible - whereas once the genie is out of the bottle, you really *can't* make an unsealed class sealed in a source compatible way, unless you can guarantee that no-one *has* derived from the class.

Comment: Bloch's advices are generally **not** applicable to most developers. Most people don't release public APIs to millions of users that last decades. Like OP, they work in-house, the economics of API evolution is completely different. Backward incompatible changes are not only possible and allowed, they are daily activities.

Comment: @irreputable: Classes don't have to be public outside a company to be widely used by thousands of people unknown to the original developer, of course. Plenty of developers work in large institutions with large internal systems. I think it's reasonable to try to design an API well, but *not* to try to design it with every possible subclassing scenario in mind.

Comment: @JonSkeet: interesting example.  I would contend that the feasibility of moving from sealed to unsealed is the precise problem; users have coded against the expectation of "sealedness"; when that expectation is broken by unsealing the code, the implications will be silent and potentially very dangerous.  Making an unsealed class sealed will have IMMEDIATE implications that will, if necessary, break a build.  It's the difference of allowing silent failures to creep in through changing expectations, or causing an immediate failure which requires direct attention to fix.  I prefer the second.

Comment: @Paul: It's definitely something which shouldn't be taken lightly. But at least it's possible. I agree in general, that causing immediate failures is good if there *has* to be breakage.

Comment: Correction is due towards the opposite direction Bloch's been selling. Does anyone dare to ever write a public mutable field? No matter how logical it is for your particular case, you'll be burned by outrageous disciples who have acquired the righteous way from the good Book.

Answer (score 19):

It is my opinion that architectural design decisions are made to communicate to other developers (including future maintenance developers) something important.

Sealing classes communicates that the implementation should not be overridden. It communicates that the class should not be impersonated. There are good reasons to seal.

If you take the unusual approach of sealing everything (and this is unusual), then your design decisions now communicate things that are really not important - like that the class wasn't *intended* to be inherited by the original/authoring developer.

But then how would you communicate to other developers that the class *should* not be inherited because of something? You really can't. You are stuck.

Also, sealing a class doesn't improve readability. I just don't see that. If inheritance is a problem in OOP development, then we have a much larger problem.

Comment: If a class is sealed, then code using it is more readable because you don't have to consider any variance in the semantics. You know how it will behave more simply.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'd contend that that readability improvement really comes from the implied assurance that the semantics won't change; in the situation posed by the OP, however, the default usage of sealed completely defeats that implied assurance, therefore defeating the readability benefit.

Comment: We're going to have to agree to disagree on that one, @JonSkeet. A sealed class could have a long lineage of inheritance itself. Complexity is not contained by sealing it. In fact, sealing it doesn't do anything for readability. It's like you are refering to Sealed as "Locked" or something. Sealing just prevents inheritance.

Comment: @Paul: Then we disagree :) I know I'm a lot more comfortable working with sealed classes. Then again, I'm also more comfortable working with immutable classes - and an unsealed class can't guarantee immutability, either...

Comment: @JonSkeet: not to get too far into the discussion here in comments, but I find that exhaustive unit tests give me that assurance by explicitly defining the contract expected by the code.

Comment: @Jerry: I don't know what you mean about "Locked", and it doesn't matter if the sealed class itself has a long inheritance hierarchy - I know nothing else is going to override its behaviour.

Comment: @Paul: In many cases you can't have unit tests against every possible subclass that someone ends up passing into your code. Someone writing a subclass may violate one of your assumptions without realizing it, unless you've got *really* explicit contracts... and I find you need to write *fewer* contracts for sealed classes, as you don't need to document aspects where one part of the implementation calls another.

Comment: @JonSkeet: agreed, but now we're into terminology: I'd contend that tests that test against subclasses someone can pass into your code are integration tests, and those serve a different purpose (and yes, I'm profoundly familiar with the gray areas involved).  I'm just saying, my experience has been that unit tests have served the purpose of providing that explicit level of guarantee of behaviour; that said, it's true that they don't provide that guarantee for integration functionality, but IMO, that's why good mocking is important.

Comment: @Paul: This was why I said to start with that it was contentious :) I doubt that we'll end up with agreement, to be honest...

Comment: @JonSkeet: well, I think we can agree on that... :)  And, I'll be honest, your experience certainly carries a lot of weight, and I'll be looking at these things with an eye to the way you've mentioned in the future...

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to think that I'm a reasonably-experienced programmer and, if I've learned nothing else, it's that I am remarkably bad at predicting the future.

Typing sealed is not hard, I just don't want to irritate a developer down the road (who could be me!) who discovers that a problem could be easily solved with a little inheritance.

I also have no idea how sealing a class makes it more readable.  Are you trying to force people to prefer composition to inheritance?

Comment: +1 for acknowledgement of the difficulty of precognition.  :)

Comment: You're right, we can't predict the future - so why not choose the least restrictive option, in terms of future change? Once you've made a class unsealed and someone has derived from it, you can't change that decision. If you want to *unseal* a class later, that can be done without breaking anything. Don't invite subclassing until you know you need it - at which point you'll know *why* you need it, so you can design for that aspect of inheritance.

Comment: I dont necessarily agree. You have to design a class with subclassing in mind if you really want to add some value to inheritance. What is the point of inheriting a class if you have the same access to its internal state as you would have by simply using a 'has a' relationship. The former entails the use of a protected state and set of protected "tools" which means that you consciosuly have to design the class with subclassing in mind.

Comment: @JonSkeet: here's the thing; if I don't want to invite subclassing, I won't write code in an object oriented language that has subclassing and inheritance as a default.  In effect, the default behavior of C# (and Java) to not have their classes sealed indicates that those tools are designed with an expectation of subclassing; if you have a desire for the default behaviour to be significantly different, I'd suggest that perhaps you're looking for a different tool.  (And yes, I'm aware of whom I'm speaking to, here...  :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: if someone's inherited from my class, I have to hope that they had a good reason to do so.  Like I said in my cop-out answer, I'm bad at seeing into the future and I'm probably not that bright to boot.  I have no problem imagining that someone could figure out a way to solve a problem by inheriting from a class.  As far as sealing it until that point, I don't disagree with you, it's just that the point isn't persuasive enough to change my coding habits.  You read it as inviting subclassing, I read it as allowing it.

Comment: @48klocs: Consider three developers, who don't know each other. One writes a class, another subclasses it, a third uses it. It's a lot of work for the *first* developer in order to help the second and third developers to end up with code which can interoperate well...

Comment: @irreputable: not really feasible for reasonable definitions of "maintain" and for the observed range of "old".  :)

Answer (score 7):

***© Jeffrey Richter***

> There are three reasons why a sealed
>   class is better than an unsealed
>   class:
>
> - **Versioning**: When a class is originally sealed, it can change to
>     unsealed in the future without
>     breaking compatibility. However, once
>     a class is unsealed, you can never
>     change it to sealed in the future as
>     this would break all derived classes.
>     In addition, if the unsealed class
>     defines any unsealed virtual methods,
>     ordering of the virtual method calls
>     must be maintained with new versions
>     or there is the potential of breaking
>     derived types in the future.
> - **Performance**: As discussed in the previous section, calling a virtual
>     method doesn’t perform as well as
>     calling a nonvirtual method because
>     the CLR must look up the type of the
>     object at runtime in order to
>     determine which type defines the
>     method to call. However, if the JIT
>     compiler sees a call to a virtual
>     method using a sealed type, the JIT
>     compiler can produce more efficient
>     code by calling the method
>     nonvirtually. It can do this because
>     it knows there can’t possibly be a
>     derived class if the class is sealed.
> - **Security**: and predictability A class must protect its own state and not
>     allow itself to ever become corrupted.
>     When a class is unsealed, a derived
>     class can access and manipulate the
>     base class’s state if any data fields
>     or methods that internally manipulate
>     fields are accessible and not private.
>     In addition, a virtual method can be
>     overridden by a derived class, and the
>     derived class can decide whether to
>     call the base class’s implementation.
>     By making a method, property, or event
>     virtual, the base class is giving up
>     some control over its behavior and its
>     state. Unless carefully thought out,
>     this can cause the object to behave
>     unpredictably, and it opens up
>     potential security holes.

Comment: Can you explain this statement: “In addition, if the unsealed class defines any unsealed virtual methods, ordering of the virtual method calls must be maintained with new versions or there is the potential of breaking derived types in the future.” Which method calls is he talking about?

Answer (score 5):

Frankly I think that classes not being sealed by default in c# is kind of weird and out of place with how the rest of the defaults work in the language.

By default, classes are `internal`.
By default fields are `private`.
By default members are `private`.

There seems to be a trend that points to least plausible access by default. It would stand to reason that a `unsealed` keyword should exits in c# instead of a `sealed`.

Personally I'd rather classes were sealed by default. In most ocassions when someone writes a class, he is not designing it with subclassing in mind and all the complexities that come along with it. Designing for future subclassing should be a conscious act and therefore I'd rather you explicitly have to state it.

Comment: It would have been intersting if C# required abstract in order to inherit a class (or some other keyword to indicate it is not sealed). But that's not how it turned out. And I certainly rely on inheriting a class on a whim these days. It could have been. I'm probably glad it didn't turn out like that.

Answer (score 5):

There shouldn't be anything wrong in inheriting from a class.

You should seal a class only when theres a good reason why it should never be inherited.

Besides, if you seal them all, it will only decrease maintainability. Every time someone will want to inherit from one of your classes, he will see it is sealed, then he'll either remove the seal (mess with code he shouldn't have to mess with) or worse: create a poor implementation of your class for himself.

Then you'll have 2 implementations of the same thing, one probably worse than the other, and 2 pieces of code to maintain.

Better just keep it unsealed. No harm in it being unsealed.

Answer (score 3):

"...consider[ing] how their classes should be sub classed..." shouldn't matter.

At least a half dozen times over the past few years I've found myself cursing some open source team or another for a sloppy mix of protected and private, making it impossible to simply extend a class without copying the source of the entire parent class.  (In most cases, overriding a particular method required access to private members.)

One example was a JSTL tag that almost did what I wanted.  I need to override one small thing.  Nope, sorry, I had to completely copy the source of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

I only seal classes if I am working on a reusable component that I intend to distribute, and I don't want the end user to inherit from it, or as a system architect if I know I don't want another developer on the team to inherit from it. However there is usually some reason for it.

Just because a class isn't being inherited from, I don't think it should automatically be marked sealed.  Also, it annoys me to no end when I want to do something tricky in .NET, but then realize MS marks tons of their classes sealed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very opinionated question that's likely to garner some very opinionated answers ;-)

That said, in my opinion, I strongly prefer NOT making my classes sealed/final, particularly at the beginning.  Doing this makes it very difficult to infer the intended extensibility points, and it's nearly impossible to get them right at the beginning.  IMHO, overuse of encapsulation is worse than overuse of polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Your house, your rule.

You can also have the complementary rule instead: a class that can be subclassed must be annotated; nobody should subclass a class that's not annotated so. This rule is not harder to follow than your rule.

Answer (score 1):

I find that sealed / final classes are actually pretty rare, in my experience; I would certainly not recommend suggesting all classes be sealed / final by default.  That specification makes a certain statement about the state of the code (i.e., that it's complete) that is not necessarily always true during development time.

I'll also add that leaving a class unsealed requires more design / test effort to make sure that the exposed behaviours are well-defined and tested; heavy unit testing is critical, IMO, to achieve a level of confidence in the behaviour of the class that appears to be desired by the proponents of "sealed".  But IMO, that increased level of effort translates directly to a high level of confidence and to higher quality code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like that way to think. Java and c# are made to be OOP languages. These languages are designed in a way where a class can have a parent or a child. That's it.

Some people say that we should always start from the most restricting modifier (private, protected...) and set your member to public only when you use it externally. These people are ,to me, lazy and don't want to think about a good design at the beginning of the project.

My answer is: Design your apps in a good way now. Set your class to seal when it needs to be sealed and private when it needs to be private. Don't make them sealed by default.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of a sealed class to take away the inheritance feature from the user so they cannot derive a class from a sealed class.Are you sure you want to do that. Or do you want to start having all classes as sealed and then when you need to make it inheritable you will change it .. Well that might be ok when every thing is in house and in one team but incase other teams in future use your dlls it will be not possible to recompile whole source code everytime a class needs to be unsealed .... 
I wont recommend this but thats just my opinion